# How to detect the touch only in a part of the screen?

Tags: android, position, touch

for my application i want to detect when the user touch a part of the screen, for example, supposing that the screen is 800 pixels high, only if it touches from 500 pixels to 800 pixels, considering the height. Is it possible?

I tried this:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
  float x_forOnTouch = event.getX();
  float y_forOnTouch = event.getY();
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  What have you tried?  Hint - just ignore touches you don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
private static final TOP_BORDER = 800;
private static final BOTTOM_BORDER = 500;

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    float x_forOnTouch = event.getX();
    float y_forOnTouch = event.getY();
    if (y_forOnTouch > BOTTOM_BORDER && y_forOnTouch < TOP_BORDER){
        processTouches(); //do what you want
    }
}
```